# how to send sms in android using phonegap 2.3.0?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have developed phonegap application using 2.3.0 version.This Application has too 
    many phone plugins sucha as, downloader,pdfviewer,statusbarnotification,video.Now 
    i want to implement the sms plugin into the same application.i have tried to 
    implement the sms plugin with this app, but not working. i thing it is confusing 
    with multiple version of cordova.So please clear my issue that, how to include 
    and write the send sms code for sending sms using phonegap and how to include sms 
    plugin into my application.share the answer with me very clearly.thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SMS plugin is for phonegap 2.3.0

[SendSmsCordovaPlugin](https://github.com/dimitrismistriotis/SendSmsCordovaPlugin)

Sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    sendSmsDemo = function() {
                        cordova.exec(function(winParam) {
                                // Use the following line if json2 library is present.
                                // Available from Douglas Crockford's github page here:
                                // https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js
                                console.log( JSON.stringify(winParam) );
                                alert(winParam.sms_send);
                            }
                            , function(error) {
                                alert("An error has occurred");
                                console.log("An error has occurred");
                                // Please refer to previous comment about json2 library.
                                console.log( JSON.stringify(error) );
                            }
                            , "SendSms"
                             ,"SendSms"
                             , ["TESTNUM", "This is random text."]);
                    }
                    </script>
```

Comment: please can u give me any sample code using this plugin for send sms.

Comment: Added the sample, it was inside assets/www